# Reducer изменения React

Tags: reactjs, redux

Как правильно изменять параметр в объекте?

```
const initialState = {
    user: {id: , type:, },
};

case SET_USER_TYPE:
return {
    ...state,
    user: action.payload,
};
```

Мне надо вернуть не весь user, а только user.type

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState = {
    user: {id: , type:, },
};

case SET_USER_TYPE: {
    const user = {...state.user, type: action.payload };
    return {
        ...state,
        user
    };
}
```